# Does SAP Learning Solution support LTI integration? If not, how would I add support?

Tags: netweaver, sap-bw, lti

I have a client that uses [SAP Learning Solution](https://help.sap.com/erp_hcm_ias_2013_02/helpdata/en/9a/03df43d81b430c9cd4e741914eafa2/frameset.htm), they want to make use of courses on a custom system that we have made. Our system supports being an LTI provider. LTI ([Learning Tools Interoperability](http://www.imsglobal.org/activity/learning-tools-interoperability)) is a standard developed by IMS Global, it's built on top of OAuth.

Does anyone know if SAP supports LTI already? (I can't find any indication that it does, but I wanted to check).

Does anyone know how we would go about adding support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMS Certified Product Directory does *not* list SAP as an LTI certified product. So it looks like there is no support unfortunately.
https://www.imsglobal.org/cc/statuschart.cfm

Comment: Thanks for providing the info, much appreciated.